# Java function with two parameter list one as an array of integers and second as an integer

Tags: java, algorithm

anyone to help me with an hint on how i can achieve this question, 
a java function that takes an array of integers and an integer as arguments and adds the integers in an array and compares its sum with the integer passed in as a second integer.

this is what i'm thinking about, first do a quick sort in case the array is not sorted, then 
do a Binary search to look for the integer (second argument integer) if it exists in the array
if it does not exist, then add the integers in the array so that i get a sum which is less or equal to the integer (second argument integer) for example

```
int fun(a[3,6,1,7,8], 4){
  /*sorting and searching code here and addition code of the array and comparing here*/
}
```

out put 3, 1 .  are chosen 3+1 = 4.

Comment: Why do you need to do any sorting?

Comment: There appears to be a mismatch between what you were asked to do and what you're trying to do. Sorting? Searching? Why are they involved when the question only mentions summation and comparison?

Answer (score 0):

"a java function that takes an array of integers and an integer as arguments and adds the integers in an array and compares its sum with the integer passed in as a second integer."

Why do you need to sort and do a binary search here? May be i am missing what you mean.. but you are trying to just calculate the sum of integers in the array and compare the sum with the second argument?

Comment: This is not an answer. Please make clarifications like this as comments.

Comment: @David ok, but for some reason i an not able to see the comment link on a new question thats why i keep using the answer box. I can see the comment link only if there is a prior answer or comment to the original question..

Answer (score 0):

I think sorting and searching and then adding Array(If element not found) is bit low performance you should directly add up all the Array element and compare this with second argument.

You can also use ArrayList instead of Array which provide you much more functionality than Array.